# C# 4.0 - 3 value pairs (possibly more). Sort based on values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, logic, sortedlist

This is a tough one to phrase as a search query and I'm having no luck. And the more I think about it, it is more a logic question than a syntax one. However I am a newby to C# (8 years php) and I am currently building my third windows forms app so there may be a method built to do just what I want.

What I am doing is reading a date format given by the user as a single string and breaking it into parts to be assigned to an Array, or from what I have seen in my searches for Associative Arrays, maybe a SortedList or Dictionary.

e.g.

```
SortedList<string, int> resultArray = new SortedList<string, int>();
string dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd" // Just and example

int yearPos = dateFormat.IndexOf("yyyy");
int monthPos = dateFormat.IndexOf("MM");
int dayPos = dateFormat.IndexOf("dd");

resultArray.Add("yearPos", yearPos);
resultArray.Add("monthPos", monthPos);
resultArray.Add("dayPos", dayPos);

// So, resultArray expressed as an array looks like:
// resultArray["yearPos"] = 0
// resultArray["monthPos"] = 4
// resultArray["dayPos"] = 6

// Sort List and reassign keys (or values) based on their position value (which is unique)
// ???????

return resultArray;
```

Ideally, the finished result that I am after for this collection/array is to have the members ranked by the value of their position in the string. Like this:

```
// resultArray["yearPos"] = 1
// resultArray["monthPos"] = 2
// resultArray["dayPos"] = 3
```

The reason I am trying to do this, is because the same date format is used to pull out a real date from a file using Regex.Match. And I want to use these new values to know which group element of the match to use for each portion of the date.

Any help getting my head around this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use the Date class directly to get the values for year, month and day?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073389/sort-array-list-of-structure-key-value-c?

Comment: Regex, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html  If you want to parse datetimes, use a datetime parser.

Comment: MK_Dev - I am looking into that thread right now. Thank you.

Comment: David B and Anon - I could be wrong, but DateTime doesn't seem to play well with the above example format of "yyyyMMdd" (e.g. 20110223) hence the regex breakup. If you know a way how using DateTime, please let me know.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry it was my unfamiliarity with the syntax and methods. Timwi's answer below soved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("20110223", "yyyyMMdd", null, 0, out dt))
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use DateTime.TryParse.  You can pass it a formatting string and it will do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you. But one of the date formats is "yyyyMMdd" (e.g. 20110223). This method seems to return 1/01/0001 12:00:00 a.m. for any such date.